# MySQL using BETWEEN comparison with NULL

Tags: mysql, null, between

I have a query with a where condition like so:

```
WHERE A.event_date BETWEEN B.start_date AND B.end_date
```

The complexity is that if `B.start_date` is NULL, it means from time immemorial, similarly `B.end_date` is NULL, it means the present. So I still want to select a row where `A.event_date > B.start_date` and `B.end_date` is `NULL`, for example.

The long-winded way to do this is

```
WHERE A.event_date BETWEEN B.start_date AND B.end_date
   OR (A.event_date > B.start_date AND B.end_date IS NULL)
   OR (B.start_date IS NULL AND A.event_date < B.end_date)
```

Is there a more elegant solution (especially since in one query I have multiple between condition like that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`IFNULL` might help out here:

```
WHERE A.event_date BETWEEN IFNULL(B.start_date,"1900-01-01") 
                   AND IFNULL(B.end_date,now());
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. As an aside, does my above solution work? MySQL is saying there's syntax error.

Comment: It should be fine. Might be that another part of the query is not correct?

Comment: I have implemented this solution, BETWEEN + IFNULL() seems to ignore an index on the date field.

Answer (score 11):

The COALESCE() function will return the first non-null value in the parameter list. Give this a try:

```
WHERE A.event_date BETWEEN COALESCE(B.start_date,'1900-01-01') and COALESCE(B.end_date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Really would prefer coalesce more than ifnull

Answer (score 2):

**IF PERFORMANCE MATTERS...**

When I saw the [@tom-mac answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164298/2282880) I said : *nice solution, I need to test it*, and after I saw the [@mw-goodjava answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164291/2282880) and I wanted to compare.

According to this test http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2004/03/01/189.aspx, it seems to be better to use `IFNULL()` instead of `COALESCE()` function but the best is still to use `WHERE ... OR ... IS NULL` like this :

```
WHERE (A.event_date >= B.start_date OR B.start_date IS NULL)
  AND (A.event_date <= B.end_date OR B.end_date IS NULL)
```

So the query is more complex and not using `BETWEEN` but finaly I will choose that solution.