# How to find a particular year within a year range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am passing in a year, e.g. 2010

I have two columns in my table, `yearFrom` and `YearTo`

```
yearFrom            yearTo
2009                2010        *hit
2005                            *miss
2010                2015        *hit
2015                2018        *miss
2010                            *hit
```

Where hit is the row selected, and miss is it not.

Sometimes there will be a yearTo value in the column, where there isn't it will be null.

How do I formulate a where clause to accomplish this.

I have tried

```
and yearFrom >= @year and yearTo <= @year
```

but it doesn't return what I need.

Comment: Why doesn't the row with `yearFrom = 2005` hit? does a `NULL` value of `yearTo` effectively mean that it is the same as `yearFrom`?

Comment: Hi Nick, so I'm searching for a car part. So for the car made in year 2010 the part is not compatible with a 2005 car part.

Comment: So a `NULL` value in `yearTo` means the part is only valid for `yearFrom`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL using BETWEEN comparison with NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164224/mysql-using-between-comparison-with-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It looks for rows where `@year` is between `yearFrom` and `yearTo`, or if `yearTo` is `NULL`, then that `yearFrom` is the same as `@year`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE @year BETWEEN yearFrom AND yearTo
   OR yearTo IS NULL AND yearFrom = @year
```

Output:

```
yearFrom    yearTo
2009        2010
2010        2015
2010        (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/932a5e/4)

Answer (score 1):

`yearFrom <= @Year and @Year <= Coalesce( yearTo, yearFrom )`.

If `yearTo` is `NULL` then it will use `yearFrom` for the second comparison making it a single model year part.

Comment: This is a nice shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the logic backwards:

```
and yearFrom <= @year and yearTo >= @year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97b231ca913ac864da4cc9603a9f1744)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (yearTo IS NULL AND yearFrom = @year) 
      OR (yearFrom <= @year and @year <= yearTo)
```

**Output**

```
yearFrom    yearTo
2009        2010
2010        2015
2010        null
```